# Rename [wotl-eternal] -> [the-binding-of-isaac-eternal]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

In 2015 [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/217151/87579) was asked, so I created the tag [wotl-eternal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wotl-eternal) which was a free DLC for *The binding of Isaac*, and an improvement for *Wrath of the lamb* DLC.

At that time we still had the 25 characters limit for tags, so I had to improvise. Since I can't suggest a tag synonym (I miss 5 score in the above-cited tag) I think it's time to fix that, too.

My suggestions are:

- [the-binding-of-isaac-eternal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-binding-of-isaac-eternal)
- [wrath-of-the-lamb-eternal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wrath-of-the-lamb-eternal)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I renamed [wotl-eternal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wotl-eternal) to [wrath-of-the-lamb-eternal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wrath-of-the-lamb-eternal) and added [the-binding-of-isaac-eternal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-binding-of-isaac-eternal) as a synonym.

Caching may take a bit to reflect the change.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!